# synonym of 'homeroom teacher'

Tags: synonyms

A few days ago, I read a synonym of ‘***homeroom teacher***’, regretfully I remembering not from which I’ve read. And I remember the dictionary I looked up said the word is mainly used in Britain. Can you say the word?

Comment: I do not know the US system, but I think *homeroom teacher* is the closest to what is called a *form tutor* in Britain.

Comment: @Laure, Thank you so much. It's in [OALD #11](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/form_1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At my school (a grammar school in Lancashire, UK) he or she was called a form teacher (not tutor).